# adding multiple values in synchronized buffer

Tags: java, multithreading, buffer

So I have a Producer, Consumer and a shared Synchronized buffer.
The producer creates a number (that gets saved in the buffer)
And the consumer gets 5 guesses to guess the number. 
Once the consumer guesses correctly it’s asked whether it wants to play again and number of times guessed correctly is saved in the buffer.

My synchronizedBuffer class is all wrong. I don't even know where to begin to implement the second value into it. Even a little hint as to how I'm supposed to do it will be much appreciated. I'm not allowed to use array-blocking queues.

```
 //Class: Producer
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

    public class Producer implements Runnable {
        private final static Random generator = new Random();
        private final Buffer sharedLocation;

        public Producer(Buffer shared) {
            sharedLocation = shared;
        }

        public void run() {

            try {
                int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10);
                Thread.sleep(generator.nextInt(3000)); // random sleep
                sharedLocation.set(x); // set value in buffer
                System.out.printf("\n", x);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Producer done producing");
        }
    }

     //Class: Consumer
     import java.util.Random;

    import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

    public class Consumer implements Runnable {
        private final static Random generator = new Random();
        private final Buffer sharedLocation;

        public Consumer(Buffer shared) {
            sharedLocation = shared;
        }

        public void run() {

            int correct = 0;
            outerloop: for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                try {
                    int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10);

                    Thread.sleep(generator.nextInt(2000));
                    if (x == sharedLocation.get()) {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        System.out.println("correct guess was " + x);
                        correct++;
                        sharedLocation.set(correct);
                        break outerloop;
                    }
                    System.out.print(x + "\n");

                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }


    public class SynchronizedBuffer implements Buffer {
        private int buffer = -1;
        private boolean occupied = false;

        public synchronized void set(int value) throws InterruptedException {

            while (occupied) {

                System.out.println("Producer tries to write.");
                System.out.println("Consumer tries to guess");
                wait();
            } // end while

            buffer = value; 

            occupied = true;

            displayState("Producer writes " + buffer);


            notifyAll();
            buffer = value;

        } 


        public synchronized int get() throws InterruptedException {

            while (!occupied) {
            System.out.println("Consumer tries to guess.");
                displayState("Buffer empty. Consumer waits.");
                wait();
            } 
            occupied = false;


            notifyAll();

            return buffer;
        }


        public void displayState(String operation) {
            System.out.printf("%-40s%d\t\t%b\n", operation, buffer, occupied);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So the consumer puts a value in the buffer? Who's going to consume that?

Comment: Yeah the shared buffer holds one integer at a time (the number produced by the producer) and the number of correct guesses by the consumer. Each time the consumer guesses correctly, the number will increase.

Comment: But your buffer only has place for a single value. Why would the consumer put the results back in the buffer? It doesn't make sense logically.

Comment: yeah, but that's what I have to do. and i can't make any sense of it.

Comment: You should clarify the requirements. Maybe you misunderstood something. As it is, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: this is what i was given: Develop a multithreaded producer-consumer system where a producer produces a random integer number (range 1 to 10). A consumer guesses this number (5 Guesses), sees if its guess is correct. The consumer counts the number of correct guesses, and clicks a next button in order for the producer to produce another integer so that it can try guessing again.  
Note the shared buffer holds only one integer at a time and the number of correct guesses. 
The producer and consumer outputs the number of correct/incorrect before finishing.

Comment: I don't know why the number of correct guesses would be stored in the `Buffer` class, but it seems that it's just an extra variable there. That shouldn't be a problem after all that prod/cons code.

Comment: Just have another integer value in Buffer which holds the number of correct guesses. This value will be incremented when the consumer guesses it correctly and before finishing print this value.